# fullcalendar - enddate not correct

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar, and I'm able to enter event's in it. But, when I enter events, without a time, they appear to end one day earlier, so when I have the end-date of 2015-09-05, it ends on the 4th. of September, not on the 5th... I think it's because it's "the end", so on that day, it's over, so it ends one day before, but I don't want that behaviour, I want to have it shown, like the day you provide for the end is still in the time the event "runs". The interesting thing is, that if I provide a time (like 2015-09-05T14:00:00), it works, because it definetely ends on the provided day.

The question now is: How can I change this behaviour, so the event is displayed with the right time?

**edit:** the problem is really, that the day you provide, is exclusive, so it's not in the time any more.

> end    :The exclusive date/time an event ends. Optional.

The question is, how can I change this behaviour...

**edit2** I tried something like

```
var end_split = enddate.split('-');
end_split[2]= parseInt(end_split[2])+parseInt("1");
enddate = end_split[0] + "-" + end_split[1] + "-" + end_split[2];
```

this now, and it works in general, but has issues, if enddate is the 30th of a month, because then the end date saved will be the 31th, and this doesn't exist always...., so this solution won't work...

Comment: Perhaps youre facing time zone issues? You can use moment js library to handle dates.

Comment: @AdamMoszczyński I don't think so, that that are time zone issues, because the event's are correctly shown, when I enter a time as well.

Comment: What i mean by timezone issues is that in most countries time is being changed 2 times a year. Maybe in your code when you parse a date at midnight, you end up with 11PM in previous day?

Comment: I don't really parse it for midnight, it's just shown as a full-day event..

Comment: I am just trying to get clear about the question first.
The question is that you want to show the end user that the event that is specified for sep 4 as active when viewing on sep 4 and completed when viewing on sep 5 th correct?

Comment: @Geek the enddate you provide for fullcalendar, is exclusive, so e.g. if you have a daterange from 15.09 to 18.09, than this are 4 days, but only 3 days are displayed in fullcalendar, because the 18.09 is exclusive, so it is not displayed any more, but i want to have it displayed..

Comment: So am I. Could you try to post a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) reproducing your error?

Comment: if it is stubbornly exclusive why don't you give it a 24 hrs buffer?

Comment: @Geek if you read my question (edit2), than you see that I tried that, by just adding one day, but if user chooses 31th of a month, than it will not be possible to have 32th of a month as endday, so this doesn't work

Comment: Why are you splitting dates and pharsing them as int?
you can use either date.pase() method or let php do the dirty work 
as u will be rendering the calendar on each change

Comment: @Geek however I'm doing it, it will not working, doing it like this. And php will not get to run, because the page is not reloaded or something, everything is sent with AJAX.

Comment: you dont need to reload the page manually, u can use the rerender function from fullcalander library

Comment: @Geek I know, and I don't reload it, that's what I wrote. I just wanted to show you that I can't run php after adding an event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89662/discussion-between-geek-and-user3375021).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple if we follow the following steps

1. get the end time from the user as string
2. convert it to milliseconds using `milliseconds = Date.parse(enddate);`
3. Add number of milliseconds corresponding to 24 hrs with milliseconds variable
4. then change it as a date object using `var d = new Date(milliseconds);`
5. convert it to your desired format using Moment.js
6. at last send it to your php script using ajax

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same and resolved it by adding "T23:59:00" with the end date
PHP code:

```
$data_events[] = array(
             "id" => $eventid,
             "title" => $title,              
             "start" => $start_date,                 
             "end" => $end_date."T23:59:00"
         );     
echo json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));
```